# how to execute one ajax function before the other using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i am creating two ajax functions one in the traditional method and one with jquery. but when i do this the traditional method gets called first and in return i dont get some of my desired outcomes. how can i make the traditional ajax method to be translated into jquery?

here is my traditional ajax method:

```
function countFollowers() {
  var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
  var url = "checkFollowers.php?username=" + document.followForm.follow_id.value;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
      var r = xmlHttp.responseText.trim();
      if (r != "error") {
        document.getElementById('followersCount').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;

        error = true;
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  if (error == true) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

here is my jquery ajax:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.msg-icon').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent a normal postback and allow ajax to run instead

    var follow_id = $(this).find('input[name="follow_id"]').val();
    $.ajax({
      data: follow_id,
      type: "post",
      url: "followingsystem.php?follow=" + follow_id,
      success: function(data) {
      }
    });
  });
});
```

here is what i come up with so far to make the two ajax functions in  the same on click function:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.msg-icon').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); //prevent a normal postback and allow ajax to run instead

 var follow_id = $(this).find('input[name="follow_id"]').val();
 $.ajax({ 
data: follow_id, 
type: "post", 
url: "followingsystem.php?follow="+follow_id, 
success: function(data) {


  }
 }); 
  $.ajax({ 
   data: follow_id, 
  type: "post", 
  url: "checkFollowers.php?username="+follow_id, 
   success: function(data) {


}
 }); 
 });
 });
```

but it is still not executing the response text that is coming from my php file

php code:

```
   <?php
include("functions.php");
include("session.php");
require("connection.php");

    if(isset($_GET['username'])){

    $username =$_GET['username'];

    $result= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $result->bindValue(1,$username);
    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetch();
    if($result){
        echo "Followers </br>". $row["followers_count"];

    }
    else{
        echo "error";
    }
    }
  ?>
```

how will i get it to echo the $row["followers_count"] inside my span element?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The traditional method won't be called first, it will be called whenever you call the `countFollowers` function.

Comment: yes thats the thing, i am calling it this way: <button  id="follow-button1" class='msg-icon' name="follow" type="submit" value="follow" onclick="countFollowers();"> -, thus it is being called first

Comment: Stop using `onclick`, do both of them with `$(".msg-icon").on("click")`. Then they'll be executed in the order that you add the event listeners.

Comment: Maybe what you really want to do is call `countFollowers()` in the `success:` function of `$.ajax`. That will run them in order.

Comment: @Barmar but how will i execute my intended countFollowers functions with $(".msg-icon").on("click")

Comment: `$(".msg-icon").on("click", countFollowers)`

Comment: @Barmar just tried that it is not working, and not executing both now

Comment: "one in the traditional method and one with jquery" ...why? Just use jQuery for them both. Then you can chain their Promises together and ensure they're executed sequentially instead of in parallel - I assume that's what you're really asking for, although it's not 100% clear.

Comment: @ADyson thats what im trying to do but don’t know how to exactly

Comment: Convert them both to be $.ajax requests firstly. Then, run them both from the same "click" function. But...only start the second one inside the "success" callback of the first one. This ensures it cannot start until the first one has finished. (Or if you prefer to use Promises instead of the "success" callback, you'd do it inside the ".done()" method.)

Comment: @ADyson okay thats perfect, please check my edited question and tell me what i am missing

Comment: You're not running them sequentially. Tell me, does your second $.ajax call start inside the "success" of the first one (as I mentioned), or not? It's quite easy to see that it doesn't. And what's all the `xmlHttp` code doing still lying around? If you're using $.ajax then you obviously don't need that any more - it will just try to trigger a 3rd request, which you don't want.

Comment: @ADyson then can u provide me with an answer on how to fix what i mentioned above? jquery is tricky and small thing that is wrong can cause problems

Comment: now what i did is working correctly, the trick is how to get the php result to be displayed ?@ADyson

Comment: According to your latest edit, they are still not actually running sequentially as you requested. I don't think just moving some code inside a particular function is all that tricky. But I will write an answer below.

Comment: @ADyson no as per my network tab, the first ajax request is executed and then the next. now all i need is how to get the response from the php file to be shown inside the second ajax function. how do i get the echo "echo "Followers </br>". $row["followers_count"];" to be displayed. what do i have to do?

Comment: "as per my network tab, the first ajax request is executed and then the next"...really? It shouldn't be, unless you've somehow globally made all AJAX synchronous (but I don't know how you would, and it would be a terrible thing anyway. They do appear one after the other in the list, but the execution graph should show you the times when they actually occurred. The only other reason it could happen in sequence by accident is if several other requests are also happening simultaneously and they have to be queued - but you can't rely on that. I've written what I think is a better solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in the comments you wanted to run the two requests sequentially instead of in parallel. Here's an all-round better way to organise your code which both allows that, and makes the code more re-usable, more maintainable and testable, and easier to understand in general.

I've used the Promise/Deferred interface provided by jQuery and AJAX as the way to chain the requests in sequence. Notice how each call is separated into each own function (so it's re-usable), but that function returns the Deferred object from the AJAX request, so you can use it to do something else when the request finishes.

Also based on your PHP I think the call to checkfollowers needs to be a GET (because PHP checks $_GET for the input value, and that's what your original XHR call was), and also you need to set the data with an explicit "username" parameter name so it'll be recognised.

It's not clear whether your call to followingsystem.php is correct or not because I can't see the PHP code for it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.msg-icon').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent a normal postback and allow ajax to run instead
    var follow_id = $(this).find('input[name="follow_id"]').val();

    var request = follow(follow_id); //run the initial request, get back the Deferred object representing that request.

    request.done(function() { //when the first request is done, run the second one.
      checkFollowers(follow_id);
    });
  });
});

function follow(follow_id) {
  return $.ajax({
    data: { follow: follow_id},
    type: "post",
    url: "followingsystem.php?follow=" + follow_id
  });
}

function checkFollowers(follow_id) {
  return $.ajax({
    data: { username: follow_id },
    type: "get",
    url: "checkFollowers.php",
    success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById('followersCount').innerHTML = data;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, your code worked perfectly and did exactly what i wanted. i am new to jquery and ajax and still getting my way around it. your code will be very useful for me in the future. appreciate your time an effort

Comment: No problem. Hopefully you can see that this is a much more structured way to organise your code and will make it easier for you test each component, and easier to see what's going on and be able to re-use bits of functionality. Organising your code in a way that is maintainable in the longer-term is almost as important a skill as writing it in the first place.

Comment: yes i saw that your code is very clean and organized, ill keep learning jquery to master it. i am more proficient in php, but i must master the client side programming languages.

Comment: That's good, I'm sure you'll succeed. unfortunately JavaScript doesn't have as many object-oriented features as PHP and others (although it's very slowly getting a bit better), so it's harder to organise code in a good way, but there are still things you can do, like simple use of functions. It also has modules and classes now, but they aren't as useful or usable as they are in languages like PHP or C#.

Comment: Yes php is a fun and easy language that you enjoy coding in, JavaScript needs real effort to get around @ADyson

Comment: Agreed. Recently I've started to look into some WebAssembly stuff, specifically Blazor (since most of my day job is actually done in .NET) to see if it would be a viable alternative to constantly messing with JavaScript. my sense is that it might be, in certain cases.